# Date format for token {domain.now}

Tags: tokens, date-preferences

How can I configure the token {domain.now} to use the short date format?  Currently it uses  the "Complete Date and Time" format.

The site is running 5.45.3. on Drupal 9

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this in the template:

`{capture assign=notime}{domain.now}{/capture}{$notime|date_format:'%m/%d/%Y'}`

Also there is this in recent versions but it may be iffy how well it works depending on the exact civi version:

`{domain.now|crmDate:'shortdate'}`

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#date

Comment: I tried {domain.now|crmDate:'shortdate'} but it did not resolve.It only showed {domain.now|crmDate:'shortdate'} in the email.

Comment: Ok good to know. It may also matter _where_ you're using it. That newfangled stuff might only work in workflow message templates, not user-driven message templates. Even for the `capture` solution, if using in user-driven templates it will need `define('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1);` in civicrm.settings.php to [enable smarty processing](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#smarty).