# How to customize date format in a template?

Tags: message-templates

I'm creating a template for my acknowledgement letters and would like to include today's date and the date of contribution, however both {domain.now} and {contribution.receive_date} generate text which includes the time, which is unwieldy and awkward for a mailed thank you letter.

How can I remove the time from these tokens? (or re-format the date entirely?)

Comment: {domain.now|crmDate:"Full"} just spits out code instead of text in the pdf – settings->date preferences doesn't do it –– and every tutorial I see on using smarty only tells you how to install it for Joomla and Drupal. Does that mean I can't use it in wordpress?

Comment: Similar question:  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41524/date-format-for-token-domain-now. For smarty see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#smarty. It's the same for wordpress.

Comment: Related: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3072

Comment: smarty will perfectly do the job